# Stripe: same product for one time and subscription

Tags: java, stripe-payments, payment

I have a doubt on how to model the Stripe products / prices on my project.

Basically all my products by default will have 2 prices (standard / premium) and on the other side you can buy them just once (a standard payment) or create a weekly subscription for it.

The questions are:

- Can i purchase a product one time if i define the price as recurring or maybe can i create a subscription if i define the price as one time? Maybe should i define all 4 prices and chose the correct one each time?
- Is it a good idea to define multiple prices for a given product or should i create 4 products in this case?

I will potentially have thousands of products and i wouldn't like to touch any limit there, so the simpler i can keep this, the better.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify some things, if you're creating one time payments using PaymentIntents, you cannot use Prices for that (i.e. you pass an `amount: 1000` to PaymentIntents, not a Price, and there is no "link" back to the Price or Product from a PaymentIntent).

That should answer your question "Can i purchase a product one time if i define the price as recurring".

> Is it a good idea to define multiple prices for a given product

Yes, this is typically recommended.

> maybe can i create a subscription if i define the price as one time?

Subscriptions only work with `recurring` Prices.

Comment: Yep, you are right. Maybe i should have read the PaymentIntent api before asking. Thanks a lot for your help